# How does control flow from app.start() in MeanJS framework

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack, meanjs

I am trying to play around with the MEAN framework. I used their scaffolding available [here](http://meanjs.org/). But I am getting confused on how the control flow happens from the time we start the server.js [`node server.js`] file.

Adding snippets of some files, the entire code is [here](https://github.com/meanjs/mean)

**./server.js**

```
var app = require('./config/lib/app');
var server = app.start();
```

**./config/lib/app.js**

```
module.exports.start = function start(callback) {
  var _this = this;

  _this.init(function (app, db, config) {

    // Start the app by listening on <port> at <host>
    app.listen(config.port, config.host, function () {
      // Create server URL
      var server = (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'secure' ? 'https://' : 'http://') + config.host + ':' + config.port;
      // Logging initialization
      console.log('--');
      .....
      if (callback) callback(app, db, config);
    });
  });
};
```

For eg, where do the parameters come from in `_this.init(function (app, db, config){` segment when im only calling `app.start();` -

Answer (score 0):

The `function (app, db, config){...}` in `_this.init(function (app, db, config){...}` is just the function **declaration**, nothing is executed **yet**, the execution is done here (Line 26) `if (callback) callback(app, db, config);` where the passed config parameter is the **global** variable declared here `var config = require('../config')` (Line 6), the `app` parameter is declared here `var app = express.init(db);` (Line 25) and the `db` parameter is the result (database instance) coming from `mongooseService.connect` call (Line 20).

Comment: but while invoking the start function, the callback is empty.

Comment: Moreover, is `_this.init` a constructor